# How can I get sweetfx to work with The Witcher?

Tags: steam, the-witcher

Tried to run the first Witcher (EE, via Steam) using sweetfx and the "configurator", but I'm seeing no difference. I have successfully used it previously with Assassin's Creed 3.

I installed it on the game root folder and also tried to install it on the Wictcher\system folder, but neither works.

For reference, I used the most recent version of SweetFx with the configurator bundle from:
http://sfx.thelazy.net/forum/sweetfx/2/

I was unable to find any game-specific instructions for The Witcher.

Comment: Have you [disabled the in-game AA?](http://sfx.thelazy.net/games/game/83/)

Comment: It was the in-game AA!

Comment: Well then. I guess I should write that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to disable the in-game Anti-Aliasing in The Witcher in order to use SweetFX.

(And yes, you were right to drop the files in `Witcher\System`.

More details can be found [here, on the Witcher Page](http://sfx.thelazy.net/games/game/83/) in the [SweetFX Settings DB](http://sfx.thelazy.net/games/).